# How to prove that the expected depth of kth smallest element in a complete binary heap (min-heap) is O(logk)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

[image: this is part of the answer where I can not understand]

My problem is that why the probability of the second,three..k-1th smallest element in the right subheap is 1/2-1/N,while in the left subheap is 1/2+1/N.

Comment: This question is not about programming, and seems off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe this would be on-topic at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is right, but I thought pictures might help.

The sample space (or probability space) is the set of all possible outcomes. And the individual probabilities of all these exclusive outcomes will add up to 1. For example, if there are only two mutually exclusive outcomes A and B in a particular sample space, and the chance of A is 1/4, then the chance of B has to be 3/4.

In your case, there are two outcomes: either k-1th smallest node is in the left subheap of the root or k-1th smallest is in the right subheap.

[image: min heap]

Before thinking about where we put the *kth* smallest node, the sample space looks like this below. The two outcomes are represented by a square and both squares are equal size (1/2 + 1/2 = 1)

[image: fifty-fifty]

But then the proposition said something like "let's assume the kth smallest node is in one of the subheaps, and let's choose left because we feel like it". There are N-1 nodes in total to choose from (N-1 because the root is not part of this selection). Below shows where we placed the kth smallest node. The overall number of nodes from which to choose the k-1th smallest, has changed (and that fact will alter the shapes in our sample space).

[image: remove a node]

So now, the chance that the k-1th smallest node is in the left subheap has been *reduced* by (1/N-1).

And this is represented below by removing a triangle from the Black square. (It could have been any shape, but I chose a triangle). That triangle has to go somewhere, because everything has to add up to 1. Number of nodes is not relevant. We reduced the probability of one outcome by the size of that triangle, and consequently increased the probability of the other outcome by the same amount. The space looks like this now.

[image]

[A probability tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ql2qLe4UYK0) is a useful ways to think about it.

Comment: Thank you very much!And your explanation is so explicit and incisive that I can go on the study of the answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need `1/(N-1)` because we are considering the left and right subtree of the root. Hence, as the size of the tree is `N`, we have `N-1` nodes to be considered. Also, as mentioned, "Without loss of generality, we may assume that k-th smallest element is in the left subheap", so, the potential nodes in the left subheap are one less than the nodes in the right subheap. Therefore, the probability in the left subheap is `1/2 - 1/(N-1)`, and reasonably, the probability in the right subheap is `1 - the probability in the left subheap = 1 - (1/2 - 1/(N-1)) = 1/2 + 1/(N-1)`.

Comment: Oh,I can not understand why the probability of the second,third,...K-1th smallest node  in the left subheap is 1/2-1/N.In my opinion,if the number of available nodes in the left subheap is one less than that of right,the probability is 4/(N-6)(except the nodes in the last level and the root,the left and right subheap has the half of the remaining nodes (N-2)/4,.and the Kth smallest node is in the left,so the left is (N-6)/4 and the probability is 4/(N-6)).Because the kth is in left,we get 1/2-1/n,I am sorry that I can not get it.